# navigator.camera.getPicture not working with android device

Tags: cordova, sockets, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

navigator.camera.getPicture not working with android device

is gives error in command line like this

```
[phonegap] starting app server...
[phonegap] listening on 192.168.1.45:3000
[phonegap]
[phonegap] ctrl-c to stop the server
[phonegap]
[phonegap] 200 /__api__/appzip
[phonegap] 200 /socket.io/socket.io.js
[phonegap] 200 /socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1441601075309-0
[phonegap] 200 /socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1441601075345-1&sid=TbhXr9L
76eLIKtCWAAAA
[phonegap] 200 /socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1441601075367-2&sid=TbhXr9L
76eLIKtCWAAAA
[phonegap] [console.log] Event Called
```

Answer (score 1):

Please share your code where you used this function and also have you added plugin for the same in config.xml? If not plugin is

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
```

and code to use camera is

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20,correctOrientation : true,targetWidth: 700,
  targetHeight: 700,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
 });
```

Please checkout are you missing something?

Comment: In my case, I call the getPicture, but anything happens... in the browser, of course, it gives me error, but in a real device I don't have any feedback

Comment: Have you called device ready at initialisation of your app? If not then do so

Comment: Yes, I call the deviceReady but inside this function there isn't any code about the camera.... am I missing something here?